# Error: C++ literal memory mishandling

Tags: c++

I have tried a lot to debug my code but it is still not working.The whole code just crashes but there is no allover error I am presenting the code please try to debug that one.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

void write(char fname[],char text[])
{
    strcat(fname,".txt");
    ofstream w(fname,ios::app);
    w<<text;
    w<<"\n";
    w.flush();
    w.close();
    cout<<" sippy "<<fname<<"  ";
}
int main ()
{
    int login=0;
    char t[100],id[100]="Its id ",pass[100]="Its password";
    login=1;
    strcpy(t,id);
    strcat(t,"\n");
    strcat(t,pass);
    cout<<" finally ";
    write("database",t);
    getch();
    strcpy(t,id);
    getch();
    cout<<t<<"  showing t here";
    getch();
    cout<<" hope this works for now  ";
    getch();
    cout<<"\nEnter the text"<<endl;
    write(id,t);
}
```

The above mentioned code does not work on tdm gcc code blocks

Edit 1:

Ok so now the major problem has been detected it is a minor bug usually caused because of drawback of a bad programming style. As it is often suggested that if a string is passed to a function then that particular function allocates a new string at the memory of the passed string. Since the passed string is a literal the code editing the newly formed string would try to edit a read only literal memory which is an error

Literals are read only because if compiler finds the use of same literal at some different place then it would be able to use same memory to flash the contents of literal therefore it becomes a necessity to make a literal read only and use of c-style string carefully(rather std::string should be used)

Thanks to all

Comment: And why are you asking us to debug it? Why can't you debug it? Update: easy, your code crashes because you are trying to append `".txt"` to a string literal.

Comment: Why are you using all those old C string functions? Can you use `std::string` and just append using `+`? Or use a `std::ostringstream`?

Comment: Why do you use C code and functions in C++? What about `std::string` and similar stuff?

Comment: Actually i am creating a program for my school where i am not taught about c++ 11. Although i know c++ 11 but still i can't use that in school code so i use c style

Comment: `std::string` predates C++11 by about 30 years.

Comment: And if I am making some changes in string literal then why the code crashes it should edit temporary memory(memory allocated by literal)

Comment: Actually I am not taught std::string so according to my teacher how can i use something which is not taught to me??

Comment: This is not a debugging service.

Comment: string literals can be in read-only memory. On a PC they usually are.

Comment: _"it should edit temporary memory(memory allocated by literal)"_ Read only temporary memory. In fact, whether it's read-only on your system or not is irrelevant because C++ prohibits this. You may not modify literals. End of story.

Comment: I think that the problem is with your header file "conio.h". Is it available in your GCC installation?

Comment: But the older version of c++ (i.e. borland c++) it allows the code to run but   after returning from write the first cout command is not working

Comment: The more experienced users here are impatient because you apparently have not debugged your program. You should learn how to use a debugger. It's trivial with Visual Studio; you need a manual if you want to use gdb from the command line; Eclipse or other IDEs or gdb GUI frontends may be easier to use but I have no experience with those. But debugging is something you *must* learn *now.* ...

Comment: ... What you can always do is "printf debugging": clutter your code with output so that you see which line causes the error. If you had done that and consequently wondered "Why can I not append text to a string literal?" you might have  found an answer online without asking.

Comment: Borland c++ does not support proper debugging so i have to do that "cout style debugging!!"

Comment: alright thanks for your suggestions it helped me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are facing a SegFault I think this line could be the problem :

```
write("database",t);
```

because in your `write` function you use `strcat` on `fname` but you pass a read-only string.

Also, I think it might be best to use real c++ instead of c+ like :

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void my_write(std::sting & fname, std::string & text) {
    std::string file = fname + ".txt";
    std::osftream w(file, std::ios::app);
    w << text << "\n";
    w.flush();
    w.close();
}

int main() {
    std::string t = "";
    std::string id = "Its id";
    std::string pass = "Its password";
    std::string fname = "database";
    int login = 1;

   t = id + "\n" + pass;
   my_write( fname, t);
}
```

I haven't test it but the idea is here.

Comment: then try to change change `write("database",t);` with `write(strdup("database"),t);` which will allow you to modify the fname. Don't forget ta add `free(fname)`at the end of your function write and to change the type of fname with `char *`

Comment: @Harshul: make ourselves all a great pleasure: make you teacher aware of all this discussion. There are two choices: he's teaching C (not C++) so it's wrong to you to use iostream, or he's teaching C++, but he's doing it in the **very very wrong way** teaching 30+ year old bad habits, and deserves millions of kik in the ass from the entire programming community.

Comment: @Wicked `strdup` won't leave room for the `strcat`.

Comment: @molbdnilo My bad, I thought that strcat used `malloc`, we can use `char *filename = malloc((strlen("database") + 5) * sizeof($filename));` with `write(strcpy(filename, "database"), t);`

Comment: @Wicked It does use `malloc`, and it allocates exactly what's required for the duplication.

Comment: @molbdnilo That's what I thought but the man says  [The strings may not overlap, and the dest string must have enough space for the result. If dest is not large enough, program behavior is unpredictable](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat)

Comment: @Wicked Sorry, I read too fast, I thought you wrote "`strdup` uses `malloc`", and it does. `strcat` does not allocate anything. (It can't - you could for instance have passed it a decayed array.)

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia  Yes you  are right it's damn true even in our book programming with c++ written by sumita arora she has applied the same old c style.Even in my examination board C.B.S.E (Central Board of Secondary Education) India the question paper also has the same pattern (c styled) so if I want good marks then I need to use c style, I think that they are ruining my programming skills. Actually now it is a little better for me as I have learnt a little bit of c++ 11. But in the days of the starting I still remember i would create a code and saw a long list of erros in code::blocks